# Display ad in iAd Bannerview iAd Network

Tags: ios, iad

I'm working with iAd for very first time, I have integrated the app with iAd successfully. Now Its completed it working fine that displayed demo iAd banner. How do I display the ad using iAd network, I cant find any tutorial to connect the app for iAd. Is there any id or key that needs to be created and written into project files or is it completely done with iTunesConnect process?

Answer (score 3):

What you see is iAd content when you're running a development build. When you submit your app to the app store it will source ads from the true (non-development) source and display those. If the test ads work, they are displayed fully and you can interact with them then everything is ready to go. You can not see true ads while running a development build.

Comment: How can I check if the ads are really displaying before uploading to App Store?